# How do I use if-then-else statement with no else condition in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of relations and I wish to print the names of all fathers. Since there's no `else` condition, the following code doesn't work:

```
relations = [("father", "arushi", "anandan"), ("mother", "arushi", "abigale"), ("father", "anandan", "ayuta"), ("mother", "anandan", "akanksha")]

father ((r, c, f):xs) = if r == "father" then print(f)

main = do
    father (relations)
```

I do not wish to put any statement after `else`.

Comment: Well that is fundamentally impossible. Since Haskell is a pure functional programming, and IO are also values. The only way to solve this is returning a "no operation" so to speak.

Comment: `if r == "father" then print(f) else return ()` is what I would do. You HAVE to put something after `else`, but in this case `return ()` is a no-op.

Answer (score 24):

Too bad, all `if`s come with `else`s. But that's okay, there's a distinguished do-nothing `IO` action.

```
father ((r, c, f):xs) = if r == "father" then print f else return ()
```

There are many other ways to skin this cat. One is pattern matching.

```
father (("father", c, f):xs) = print f
father ((r, c, f):xs) = return ()
```

Another that is specific to monadic actions is to use `when`.

```
father ((r, c, f):xs) = when (r == "father") (print f)
```

Of course, that's just hiding the `else`, which is again `return ()`:

```
when p act = if p then act else pure () -- okay, it's actually pure, not return
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I  make `father` iterate over all the elements in list `relations`?

Comment: @SwapnilSharma If, after some attempts of your own, you still have trouble with that, some details about what you tried and where it went wrong would make a fine additional question. But it is a *separate* question from this one.

Comment: Technically, one could write the partial function `father ((r, c, f):xs) = case r of "father" -> print f`, since the `case` expression doesn't need to be exhaustive like the `if` expression does. (Which is not to day one *should* do this :) )

Answer (score 12):

The idiomatic Haskell way to solve such issues is to avoid mixing computation and I/O, when possible.

In this case, instead of "printing the names of all fathers", you can first "compute the names of all fathers" (no I/O here) and then "print the computed names" (I/O here)

```
relations = 
   [ ("father", "arushi", "anandan")
   , ("mother", "arushi", "abigale")
   , ("father", "anandan", "ayuta")
   , ("mother", "anandan", "akanksha")
   ]

-- compute only the fathers
fathers = [ f | ("father", _, f) <- relations ]

-- print them
main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ putStrLn fathers
```

No `if` needed, since `mapM_` iterates over the list for us, and all the list entries have to be printed.

Answer (score 8):

Every `if` must have an `else`.

```
father ((r, c, f):xs) =
  if r == "father"
    then print f
    else _what
```

If you try to compile that, you'll be informed that there's a hole

```
_what :: IO ()
```

So you need to manufacture something of that type. Fortunately, that's easy:

```
father ((r, c, f):xs) =
  if r == "father"
    then print f
    else pure ()
```

`pure x` does nothing and returns `x`.

Since what you're trying to do is quite common, there are two functions specifically designed for the task:

```
when :: Applicative f => Bool -> f () -> f ()
when b m = if b then m else pure ()

unless :: Applicative f => Bool -> f () -> f ()
unless = when . not
```

You can find both of these functions in `Control.Monad`.

```
father ((r, c, f):xs) =
  when (r == "father") $ print f
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write a function that *always* writes the name, but then ensure it only gets called on values containing `father`.

```
relations :: [(String,String,String)]
relations = [("father", "arushi", "anandan")
            ,("mother", "arushi", "abigale")
            ,("father", "anandan", "ayuta")
            ,("mother", "anandan", "akanksha")
            ]

printName :: (String,String,String) -> IO ()
printName (_, _, name) = print name

printFathers :: [(String,String,String)] -> [IO ()]
printFathers = fmap printName . filter (\(f, _, _) -> f == "father")

main = sequence (printFathers relations)
```

The definition of `filter` hides the logic of skipping certain elements of the list. The argument to `filter` always returns either `True` or `False`, but the result of `filter` only contains those elements for which you want to call `print`.

(`sequence`, here, just turns the list of `IO` values into the single `IO` value that `main` must be by "swapping" `IO` and `[]`. You could incorporate this into `printName` by defining it as `sequence . fmap printName . ...`, and replace `sequence . fmap foo` with `traverse foo`.)

---

Note that `if foo then bar else baz` is syntactic sugar for a complete `case` expression

```
case foo of
  True -> foo
  False -> baz
```

However, a `case` expression doesn't have to handle every possible value of the `foo` argument. You *could* write

```
father ((r, c, f):xs) = (case r of "father" -> print f) : father xs
```

It would be instructive, though, to see what happens when `r` *doesn't* match `"father"`.

Comment: `main` above has a list type, instead of an IO type (+1, since that's easy to correct)

Comment: Oh, right. I knew that you could easily change `[IO ()]` to `IO [()]`, and I knew that `main` just had to have *some* `IO` type, not necessarily `IO ()`, but then didn't quite connect those two facts correctly.

Comment: When you don't care about the resulting list, `sequence_` is marginally more efficient than `sequence`. And when, as here, you are actually doing `sequence . map` or `sequence_ . map`, there is `mapM` or `mapM_` for combining the two steps.

Comment: Indeed. Any idea why `traverse_` is not in the Prelude when `traverse/MapM` and `mapM_` are?

Comment: I guess that's because `traverse_ / for_` only require `Foldable` instead of `Applicative`, so they ended up in distinct modules, and only one of these got then merged in `Prelude`. I'm also bothered by having to import another module for the `_` variant.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the need to explain **why** an if must have an else in Haskell.

Haskell is an implementation of typed lambda calculus and in lambda calculus we have **expressions** and **values** nothing else.
In it we evaluate/reduce expressions to values or into expressions that can't be reduced any further.

Now in typed lambda calculus we add types and abstractions but we still to evaluate down to values and expressions one of these expressions being `if predicate then value else value`.
This `if` expression must reduce to a value therefore both branches of the if expression must reduce to values of the same type.
If we had an "if predicate then value" it means we would have a branch that doesn't reduce to a value.

> you can use *run*, *reduce* and *evaluate* interchangeably in the context of this answer.

When we run Haskell code we are reducing lambda terms into values or expressions that can't be reduced any further.
The compiler exists to help us write valid lambda terms.

Going by lambda calculus we see that the if statement must, when evaluated, reduce to a value (or be capable of doing so) and because Haskell is implemented typed lambda calculus an if expression in Haskell without an else wouldn't have the possibility of evaluating down to a value *all the time*.

TL;DR

The "if ... then ... else" statement should when evaluated reduce to a **value**.
As long as both branches of the if statement evaluates to the same type it evaluates correctly.

If any branch doesn't evaluate to a value or are going to evaluate to values of different types that is not a valid lambda term and the code will not typecheck.

Comment: You write, "When we run Haskell code we are reducing lambda terms into values or expressions that can't be reduced any further." This isn't quite true. An expression that can't be reduced any further is in what's called *normal form* (NF). Haskell programs are iteratively evaluated to something called *weak head-normal form* (WHNF). This basically means evaluating the *outermost constructor* of the result, or, if the result is a function, evaluating it to reach a lambda form. For an `IO` action, it means evaluating it to get *the first primitive `IO` action*.

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this style as well, & with Haskell formatting requirements. But I found that instead of placing emphasis on a required [else], one can use [else do] to include all following lines of code without an additional indention on concurrent lines, such as..

```
main = do
    --if conditions exit main, 
    if t < 1 || t > 100000 
    then return ()
    else
        do
    --code here, even with the else, 
    -- is only run when if condition above -> is false
```

Proof code can be in simpler form

```
if True
    return ()
else
    do
-- add code below this line to prove return works
```